# How to init a UIView subclass when sharing a nib with another UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have 2 UIViews that both use the same nib:

`PictureCell` and `LabelCell` that both inherit from `ParentCell`. Both of these use the nib `picturecell.xib` because their layouts are very similar.

`PictureCell` and `LabelCell` both override a method called `setImage` from `ParentCell`.

Currently `picturecell.xib`'s owner is set to `PictureCell`.

I instantiate the `PictureCell` by doing `[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"picturecell" owner:self options:nil][0];`

How would I instantiate `LabelCell`?

Comment: Are these table view cells?

Comment: Yeah they are tableview cells. The `ParentCell` class has a ton of logic and is something that's used everywhere in the app, so my new cells have to extend from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make separate xibs for each cell, and use registerNib:forIdentifier: instead of loading them the way you were. You can copy and paste the cell to the new xib, so you don't have to remake it.

**After Edit:**

I did find one way that works to share a common UI made in a xib between two cell subclasses. Instead of making a xib that's a cell, make one that is a UIView. Add all your common subviews to it, and make the file's owner the base cell class so you can hook up any outlets you've created in that class. In the base cell's init method, you can add this view as a subview of the contentView ("content" is a property created in the .h of the base cell).

```
@implementation RDBaseCell

-(instancetype) initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    if (self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]) {

        _content = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CellContent" owner:self options:nil][0];
        [self.contentView addSubview:_content];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.content.frame = self.contentView.bounds;
}
```

In the table view controller, register the class for both of your subclasses. In the init method for the subclasses, you can add any custom views that are specific for that subclass.

Comment: Yeah that works, but the one downside is in the future whenever I make a change to one nib I have to remember to make the same change to the other nib as well. This is not that great for extensibility.

Comment: @RazorStorm, I'm a little confused about what you have. You say the cells have a similar layout -- I assume that means they are not identical, but you have only one cell in your xib? Are you modifying one of the them in code to make them not identical?

Comment: Yeah I am modifying them in code to make them identical. To be clear, each cell has an `UIImageView`. If it is a `PictureCell` my code will put the user's profile picture there, if it is `LabelCell` my code will put a `UILabelView` there instead.

Comment: @RazorStorm, I can't think of a good way to make this work with one xib. Is the view hierarchy created in the xib complex? If not, it might be best to make the cells in code, and forget about xibs. You could do the common subviews setup in the base cell class, and add or change what you need to in the subclasses.

Comment: @RazorStorm, I did find one way to do this with a xib, and have updated my answer.